# how to add values in one single bar in d3 bar chart

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I want to add all same values to one bar , normally in d3 we have stacked bar concept in that we add each in separate bar 
here I have given sample running code of

http://bl.ocks.org/d3noob/8952219

and I want like suppose with this domain 2013-01,53 we have 4-5 more entries and it all should come into same bar

Comment: you are going to play outside and we have to do your work ?

Comment: why so? I am unable to find any similar kind of example all examples are related to stack or simple bar chart, if you can even give me a single example as am asking. then you can say who is going to play

Comment: I have not given the problem , only asking example for reference

Comment: you can use Grouped Bar Chart --> https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3887051 Or Stacked Bar Chart -->http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3886208

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several ways for doing this, one of them is using `nest`. In this case:

```
 var nestedData = d3.nest()
    .key(function(d) { return d.date;})
    .rollup(function(d) { 
         return d3.sum(d, function(e) {return e.value; });
    })
    .entries(data);
```

Check this demo, it will sum all the values with the same key "date":

```js
var data = [{date: "2016-01", value: 53},
            {date: "2016-01", value: 10},
            {date: "2016-02", value: 42},
            {date: "2016-03", value: 17}];

     var nestedData = d3.nest()
        .key(function(d) { return d.date;})
        .rollup(function(d) { 
             return d3.sum(d, function(e) {return e.value; });
        })
        .entries(data);

console.log(nestedData);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
```